# Issue in Implementation of Infragistics Gauge Control for multi dimension data

Tags: infragistics, gauge

I tried to bind the Infragistics Gauge control with single dimension which works fine for me but i want to bind multi dimension data by using gauge.

By multi dimensional i mean i want to show three entities in one Gauge.

Please share the way/procedure to implement that.

Comment: Which Gauge control are you using?  Infragistics has Gauge controls for ASP.NET, jQuery, Windows Forms, WPF, and Silverlight.  What is the specific object that you are using for the data source that you are binding the gauge to?

Comment: @alhalama Thanks for your time. Actually one of my friend was facing this problem, so he also put the same problem on Infragistics forums. What he want is not supported in Infragistics as of now. http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/83136.aspx

Comment: I added an answer that has a link to the product ideas page where new ideas can be submitted for the NetAdvantage for Windows Phone product.

Answer (score 1):

For the Windows Phone Gauge control this is not currently possible and should be submitted as a new product idea: http://ideas.infragistics.com/forums/192358-windows-phone